# PHP will show all the records on one row

Tags: php, html

I'm writing a forum, and my PHP code shows all the records for the selected column on a simple row.

Code:

```php
<td bgcolor="#FAB1CA">
<?php
$link = mysqli_connect("xxxx", "xxx", "xxxx", "xxxxxx");

if ($link === false) {
    die("ERROR: Could not connect. " . mysqli_connect_error());
}

if (isset($_SESSION['logged'])) {
    $sql = "Select ID from forum_question ORDER by id DESC";
    $result = mysqli_query($link, $sql);
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
        $show = $row['ID'];
            print_r($show);
    }
}

mysqli_close($link);
?>        
</td>
```

Comment: Add `echo '<br>';` on the next line after the `print_r`, if that's what you need?

Comment: What's your question?

Comment: the code will show all the records on the database on a single line, and I wanted to put them into a table each one in a different row, Im a rookie on php so thanks for answering me.

Comment: thanks, it seems I just missed the echo '<br>'; .... thank you all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<td bgcolor="#FAB1CA">
    <?php
        $link = mysqli_connect("xxxx", "xxx", "xxxx", "xxxxxx");
        if($link === false){
            die("ERROR: Could not connect. " . mysqli_connect_error());
        }
        if(isset($_SESSION['logged'])){
        $sql= "Select ID from forum_question ORDER by id DESC";
        $result = mysqli_query($link, $sql);
        while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){
            $show = $row['ID'];
            print_r($show);
            echo"<br />";
        }
       }
     mysqli_close($link);
   ?> 
 </td>
```

please echo a "br"-tag. hope your problem will be fixed.